# Parsing command line arguments and use them to initialize application that has to be implemented using abstract factory pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, function-pointers, functor

I have written an application that parses a command line and initializes the application, but is in C language. But the required application is to be written in C++. The following code snippet extracts/parses the arguments and calls respective functions.

```
void (* const OptionFuncPtr[])(char *pstr) = {
                                (SetA),(GetB), (SetC), (SetD), (Erase), (FOptions), (GOperations),
                                (ShowHelp), (SetInput), (undefined), (undefined), (SetLBit), (undefined), (undefined),
                                (OutputData), (ProgramOptions), (ReadAll), (ReadData), (SOptions), (TestMode),
                                (undefined), (VerifyData), (WOptions), (FillUnspecific), (ReadLBits), (NoProgessIndicator)
                                };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

...// some code
for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        param = argv[i];

        /* Allow parameters to start with '-' */
        if( param[0] != '-' )
            throw new ErrorMsg( "All parameters must start with '-'!" );

        if( strlen( param ) <= 1 )
            throw new ErrorMsg( "Parameters cannot be just the minus without any characters!" );

        value = param[1] - 'a';
        if(value > 26)
            throw new ErrorMsg("You have not entered a valid command line parameter");

        (*OptionFuncPtr[value])(&param[2]);
        }

//some more code
return 0;
}
```

As it can be seen, the code is in C. and I need to write it in C++. I am a noob to C++. I have read a lot of articles, but have not been to able to concrete any thing yet. Don't know how to implement this using C++.

The methods that I am calling may be from different class. I think this is achievable using functors. But not sure. It would be helpful if any one can just give a small example, from where I will carry things forward. Need to use abstract factory pattern also.

Comment: Why do you _need to_ use an abstract factory?

Comment: because the parsing would load different device drivers, and the application would be extended in future to accommodate more drivers. And also, thats the requirement (SRS).

Comment: Hmm. I understand the desire to use a factory (you already do). But why do you need an _abstract_ factory?

Comment: _the desire_ no, its more of a requirement fulfillment over the desire

Comment: In that case, I would challenge the requirement. SRS is about _what_, not _how_.

Comment: SRS & implementation details from our project lead (oops i didnt mention that). well, there's no point discussing it anyway. I need to do it, but dnt know how.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101985/discussion-between-d-7-and-rumburak).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid C++. It does what it should. If you need to make it look more like C++, you could create an abstract argument handler base class

```
struct ArgHandler
{
   virtual ~ArgHandler();
   virtual void operator(const std::string& arg) = 0;
};
```

Derive `ShowHelp` etc from those and then

```
ArgHandler& getArgHandler(int i)
{
  static std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<ArgHandler>> handlers = {std::make_pair(0, std::make_shared<ShowHelp>(), ...};

  // Add some error handling here if i is not found.
  return *(handlers.find(i)->second);
}
```

Of course, you move this free function and the static into a factory class. You can also create a hierarchy of factories and turn the whole thing into an abstract factory pattern, but honestly, I see no point in that.